# Can i create stored procedures in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Can i create stored procedures in MS Access 2010 ? If yes please tell me how

Comment: The accepted answer appears to be incorrect - see Panky's / Sergey's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create Stored Procedure & Triggers.
Check this: [How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)