# Best way to create stored procedure

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is it right that only way to create stored SQL procedure is to write VBA function like the following?

```
Public Function CreateProc()
   Dim strProc As String
   strProc = "Create Procedure qryCustByCity " & _
             "(prmCity varchar) as " & _
             "select * from Customers where City = prmCity"
   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strProc
End Function
```

Or there is a more convenient way? Something like interactive command prompt would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access is it what u looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The above could simply be created using the query design window with a little editing in SQL view, or simply choosing parameters from the right-click menu. See also [How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)

[image: parameter query]

Comment: From Access 2000 on, the right click menu included a parameter option ( I do not know about '97 ), so most certainly you can right-click for Access 2007 to get the parameter option. You can also edit in SQL view.