# Date insert in access

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, insert

I am working on access but stuck in insert queries having date time. like these queries doesn't work for me.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], 
[grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) 
VALUES('001', '#12/12/23 18:46:38+20#', '0', 'T', 'F', '+923468280124');

INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], 
[grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) 
VALUES('001', #'12/12/23 18:46:38+20'#, '0', 'T', 'F', '+923468280124');

INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], 
[grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) 
VALUES('001', '12/12/23 18:46:38+20', '0', 'T', 'F', '+923468280124');
```

[image]

Any idea? what could be wrong.

Here is my code in c#:

```
con = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
con.Open();

cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], 
[fuel_level], [grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) 
VALUES('" + genset_id + "', '" + rec_time + "', '" + fuel_level + "', '" +
grid_electricity + "', '" + genset_electricity + "', '" + genset_number + "');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have also tried this.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], 
[fuel_level], [grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) 
VALUES('" + genset_id + "', @rec_t, '" + fuel_level + "', '" + grid_electricity 
+ "','" + genset_electricity + "', '" + genset_number + "');";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@rec_t", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value 
                              = DateTime.Parse(rec_time);
```

All other insert and select queries are working fine

Comment: can you please show what your OLEDB Command code looks like also check the database and let us know what the datatype are setup as '

Comment: couldn't got you? you mean c# code?

Comment: Is the Date field data type DateTIme or Text also does the time field matter..?

Comment: date time as provided in attached snap

Comment: Please show more code want to make sure you are using OleDB connection correctly..

Comment: Did you try `YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS` format

Comment: what does the date look like in the table can you show that, want to make sure we are giving you the correct format..

Comment: If you want to store milliseconds in a date/time field you need to pass the value as a double. Presumably that's the problem you're having.

Comment: I suggest using parametrized commands as Amit Ranjan shows in his answer. If the date/time originates from a DateTime variable or property you won't have to deal with date/time formats at all. BTW, the correct date/time literal in Access queries is without quotes: `... VALUES(5, #2003-2-1 18:08:42#, 'hello')`. And use the yyyy-MM-dd format as the other can be confusing. Is `01/02/2012` `dd/MM/yyyy` Or `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query has more than one problem.  I copied this version from your comment to DJ:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels (
    [genset_id],
    [rec_time],
    [fuel_level],
    [grid_electricity],
    [genset_electricity],
    [genset_number]
    )
VALUES (
    '001',
    '#12/11/2023 2:46:38 PM#',
    '0',
    'T',
    'F',
    '+923468280124'
    );
```

The problems are:

1. You're attempting to insert the string, `'#12/11/2023 2:46:38 PM#'` into the Date/Time field `rec_time`.  Discard the single quotes to make that value a Date/Time literal instead of a string: `#12/11/2023 2:46:38 PM#`
2. You're attempting to insert the string, `'T'` into the Yes/No field `grid_electricity`.  Use `True` without quotes instead.
3. You're attempting to insert the string, `'F'` into the Yes/No field `genset_electricity`.  This is the same issue as problem #2.  Use `False` without quotes.

Use Access' query designer to create a new query.  Switch it to SQL View and paste in this statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels (
    [genset_id],
    [rec_time],
    [fuel_level],
    [grid_electricity],
    [genset_electricity],
    [genset_number]
    )
VALUES (
    '001',
    #12/11/2023 2:46:38 PM#,
    '0',
    True,
    False,
    '+923468280124'
    );
```

If there are any remaining problems with that statement, work them out in Access before bothering with the `c#` code to create the statement.

Or better, use the parameters query approach.  Maybe you can get that working once you resolve those issues with the Yes/No fields.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
try
{

  con = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
  con.Open();

  cmd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], [grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",DateTime.Parse("12/12/2009 11:34:55"));
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (OleDBException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Update:

If you are using Access 2010, then you can also use Stored Procedures on MSAccess. See this article for more [How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)

Comment: OleDB does not really use parameter names, it's index based, which is why you can pass the question mark for each one of your parameters as the name. You do have to make sure your parameters are in the same order as your query statement.

Comment: @DJKRAZE : Yes, parameters must be aligned. You are true.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following this way you can trap the Exact Exception first so we can determine what field the Insert is failing on .. I think the Date you are passing is odd try passing "MM/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS"

```
try
{

  con = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
  con.Open();

  cmd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], [grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) VALUES('" + genset_id + "', '" + rec_time + "', '" + fuel_level + "', '" + grid_electricity + "', '" + genset_electricity + "', '" + genset_number + "');";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (OleDBException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

if you decide you use the AddWithParameters() method you may want to try something like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTime.Parse("12/11/2023 2:46:38"));
```

or the correct way to do it would be something like this

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels[genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], [grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number])
 VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')", genset_id, rec_time, fuel_level, grid_electricity, genset_electricity, genset_number)";
```

I would recommend creating variables and assigning the values to the variables

Create and assign variables to these values 
this way you don't have to have such a nasty looking insert statement with all the commas

**genset_id, rec_time, fuel_level, grid_electricity, genset_electricity, genset_number**

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: my query INSERT INTO tbl_fuel_levels([genset_id], [rec_time], [fuel_level], [grid_electricity], [genset_electricity], [genset_number]) VALUES('001', '#12/11/2023 2:46:38 PM#', '0', 'T', 'F', '+923468280124');

Comment: you normally use # sign when doing Selects.. I don't think you need it for Date

Answer (score 0):

To format a date in a MSAccess query you use just the `#` symbols:

```
#12/12/23 18:46:38+20#
```