# error while executing a ms-access query

Tags: c#

I created a query to insert into two ms access tables at a time in c#. I got the exception

> {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Characters found after end of SQL
>   statement.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   CompanyDetails.Model.CompanyDetailsModel.setCompanyDetailsToDB(CompanyDetailsDataList
>   _cmpDetailsList) in E:\Project\PBAttendence\ModifyPrivileage\CompanyDetails\Model\CompanyDetailsModel.cs:line
>   62}

my sample code is given below please solve my problem. sorry for my bad English.

```
int companyID = _cmpDetailsList[0].CompanyID;
                    string companyName = _cmpDetailsList[0].CompanyName;
                    string contactID = _cmpDetailsList[0].ContactID;
                    string companyAddress = _cmpDetailsList[0].CompanyAddress;

                    if (companyID == -1)
                    {
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('" + companyName + "','" + companyAddress + "','" + contactID + "');Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) values (" + "Select [UserID] from UserDetails;" + "," + "Select @@identity;" + "); ", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OleDbCommand upcmd = new OleDbCommand("update CompanyDetails set [CompanyName] = '" + companyName + "',[CompanyAddress] = '" + companyAddress + "',[ContactID] = '" + contactID + "' where [CompanyID] = @cmpID;", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        upcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpID", companyID);
                        upcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
```

now i split into two insert command but i got the error {System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error. in query expression 'Select [UserID] from UserDetails;

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('" + companyName + "','" + companyAddress + "','" + contactID + "');", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) values (" + "Select [UserID] from UserDetails;" + "," + "Select @@identity" + ");", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
```

Comment: there are 2 queries in your question , it would be helpfull if you pointed out which line throws the error(hint: it's line 62 ;) ).

Comment: @Kristof insert query throws an error.

Comment: i think Select [UserID] from UserDetails; in your Insert statement is the problem. Do you want to insert it for multiple users?

Comment: "); " this space after semicolon might be the issue.

Comment: @VishalVaishya yes absolutely i want to insert into multiple users

Comment: I guess your second insert statement should be like this: Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) Select [UserID], @@identity from UserDetails;

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line of code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('" + companyName + "','" + companyAddress + "','" + contactID + "');Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) values (" + "Select [UserID] from UserDetails;" + "," + "Select @@identity;" + "); ", conn);
```

You have two `insert` statements in the same `OleDbCommand`. Try to move this into two different steps:

1. Insert into CompanyDetails table
2. Insert into UserCompanyDetails table

Hope this helps you

Comment: is possible to execute two queries at a time

Comment: @Siva yes it is possible but you have to create a Stored Procedure to do it for you. You can't add two separate queries into the same OleDbCommand, that will generate the error that you have posted. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access) is a good post on how to create Stored procedures in Access. You can go either way, I think is easier to split your code into two separate OleDbCommands because I've assumed that you're not using Stored procs

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have ; in queries in Access. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760224.aspx You will have to do the two inserts separately as suggested by @juanreyesv

You will have to do 3 queries,

1. Do the insert using your sql: `"Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('" + companyName + "','" + companyAddress + "','" + contactID + "')`
2. Get the @@identity using 
   `Select @@identity` and store it in a variable say `idnt`
3. Use the identity value obtained in 2. to do the third insert:
   `"Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) 
   Select UserID, " + idnt.ToString() + " from UserDetails"`

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: i try your query OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('" + companyName + "','" + companyAddress + "','" + contactID + "'); Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) Select X.UserID, Y.CompID from (Select UserID from UserDetails) X, (Select @@identity As CompID) Y;", conn); still i got the same error

Comment: Please debug and post the sql statement that is generated. You can do this this by adding a extra variable: `string strSql = "Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('" + companyName + "','" + companyAddress + "','" + contactID + "'); Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) Select X.UserID, Y.CompID from (Select UserID from UserDetails) X, (Select @@identity As CompID) Y;"; OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL);`

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see what is the value of strSQL and post it.

Comment: this is the value in strSQL Insert into CompanyDetails([CompanyName],[CompanyAddress],[ContactID]) values ('TCS','adfasf','ad'); Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) Select X.UserID, Y.CompID from (Select UserID from UserDetails) X, (Select @@identity As CompID) Y;

Comment: I think you cannot do two inserts in one statement. You will have to do the two inserts separately as suggested by @juanreyesv.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , it would have been easier with the raw sql command then your code generating the sql.
You might consider making a stored procedure since your command is getting kinda complex
If i'm correct , what you are currently trying to do is :

```
Insert into table1(x,y,z) values a,b,c;
Insert into table2(x,y) values select * from table3; , @@identity
```

The second sql command is invalid in both syntax and logic, your @@identity won't be static since you're inserting new records during your command.
My recommendation would be to do something like this :

```
Insert into table1(x,y,z) values a,b,c;
declare @table1Id int = @@identity
Insert into table2(x,y) select colA, @table1Id from table3;
```