# select data from more than 1 table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access

I am using access as my db and am having trouble trying to get my query to select the correct data. At the moment my query seems to be returning all records in the tables when really for this particular value in the WHERE clause, it should be returning only 1.

The idea is to use the 'Requests Boxes' table based on the value in the WHERE clause and use those value to pull data from the 'Boxes' table. I would be grateful if someone could point out my newbie error. I would like to add that I inherited this db and have no option to change it. Many thanks

My db setup is as follows.

**Requests Boxes**

Request no

Box

**Boxes**

Box

CustRef

```
sql = "SELECT [Request Boxes].[Request no], [Request Boxes].Box, Boxes.Box, Boxes.CustRef " &
                  "FROM [Request Boxes], Boxes WHERE [Request Boxes].[Request no] = '" & item & "'"
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
sql = "SELECT [Request Boxes].[Request no], [Request Boxes].Box, Boxes.Box, Boxes.CustRef " &
                  "FROM [Request Boxes] INNER JOIN Boxes ON [Request Boxes].Box = Boxes.Box " &
                  "WHERE ((([Request Boxes].[Request no]) = '" & item & "' )" &
                  "AND ([Request Boxes].[Customer] = '" & customer2 & "') AND (Boxes.Status = '" & status & "'))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the two tables with your `FROM` clause...

```
FROM [Request Boxes], Boxes
```

This means you will get all the `Boxes` rows, attached to the `Request Boxes` row you are correctly selecting. To pick out the `Boxes` row matching, add an `ON` clause to the `FROM`...

```
FROM [Request Boxes], Boxes ON [Request Boxes].[Box] = [Boxes].[Box]
```

This will ensure that only the matching `Boxes` row is attached to the `[Request Boxes]` row.

Comment: Brian, just 1 problem. The query is failing because of this line (Boxes.Status = '" & status & "') in my updated code. If I remove line then it displays fine. I have debugged and I know the correct values are being passed. Where have I gone wrong. Thanks

Comment: One little advice, using Sql Queries in vb.net or C# is not that good. It's always better to write those queries into Stored Procedures of SQL Server and call them from your code.

Comment: @user1532468, is your status a number? If so, you don't want the single quotes.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa Thanks for heads up. Are there any good tuts for SP in access. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 you will find a good answer in [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)