# Selecting data from multiple tables?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to use an SQL statement that selects data from multiple tables in access how would i go about doing that?

So it would look something like

```
    Select * From Tbl_Car and Tbl_Customer where CarID = @SearchID and CustomerID = @SearchID
```

Comment: Do the tables relate to each other or contain the same columns and type of data? If they just relate to each other then you will need to join them together. if they contain the same columns you will need to union them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select data from more than 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631362/select-data-from-more-than-1-table)

Comment: The tables do not relate to each other at all i just want to select data from both tables.

Comment: If there is no relationship between the tables why do want to get data from them at the same time?

Comment: If there are no relationship, then you need two queries. Or you could always call a store procedure that would return two cursors.