# How to save the stored procedure in the MS Access database file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

I am creating the following stored procedure (SP) from forms C# application:

```
string cmdText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE User_SelectOne as
                                SELECT * FROM Userinfo";
```

The ExecuteNonQuery command runs successfully and I am able to run and retrieve the SP results. However, if I open the MS Access database the newly created SP is not present. I have to create procedure every time I run the application, which means the SP object remains in working memory and not on disk. Is there a way to store the SPs created from code?
The question described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access) does not describe the creation of the SP from C# and it does not demonstrate how to save the SP on the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)

Comment: Dear @Jacob I saw that question. It does not give the solution to save the SP on the file

Comment: Maybe [you are overwriting your mdb file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34396eb0-95f5-4286-bacf-837e5b455892/c-how-to-save-changes-in-dataset-to-mdb-file?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) when you start your program?

Comment: @Crowcoder I opened the file during and after the program execution and the file is the same i.e. without the newly created SP

Comment: Is the data that you add/update/delete also gone next time you open it?

Comment: No, the data and all the stored queries (using MS Access UI) are right into the place. That's what makes me confused

Comment: Your program is not using the same file that you are looking at. Check if you have the database file in the BIN\DEBUG folder or BIN\x86\DEBUG folder when you run the program inside Visual Studio,

Comment: Thank you @Steve. However how do use only one copy of the DB file and not recreate it every time you run the program? Or just use the file properties like "Do not copy"

Comment: You should set the property to copy if newer. More info here [Why saving changes to the database fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails)